# Is my Graphics Card slowing the entire system down?

Tags: graphics-card, performance

OK, so I have just put together a new machine, using all new shiney parts except my graphics card, which I thought would be man enough given that I'm not using this a gaming machine at all.

The graphics card is bringing the Windows Experience Index down considerably (results below), but I am surprised at the effect it appears to be having, so think it might be something else?

The problem I am getting is that rendering actions is slow, for example, opening a new tab in Firefox, or even just typing this question into the browser here. The text is appearing a few seconds after I type it. Opening a new browser tab is not as "instant" as I would expect and scrolling web pages is slightly jerky.

Opening files and programs is lightening fast, as I would expect, but it's these basic user actions that are slow and frustrating.

Any tips gratefully received.

The graphics card is an NVIDIA GeForce 8400 GS and drivers are all up to date.

[image]

Comment: Is the video card "integrated"?

Comment: No. There is an onboard graphics card, but it only has an HDMI output port, my monitors have VGA or DVI and I have no HDMI to DMI leads, so I can't use the onboard graphics at the moment.

Comment: Interesting that your NVidia 8400 appears to be sharing video memory.  Is your onboard video disabled in your BIOS, or is it active so that you appear to have two display adapters working at the same time?  Try going into your BIOS, disabling the onboard video, and setting the amount of shared memory as low as possible.

Comment: OK, I will give that a go. I have only one monitor running right now, but will run two, although the NVIDIA card is capable of running two, so disabling the onboard graphics will be fine.

Comment: Keep in mind that the WEI score is always just the value of the lowest subcategory.  It doesn't mean everything else is slow as a result of one heading being low scoring.

Comment: @Shinrai yeh, I realise that, it wouldn't bother me except for this slow scrolling issue. Disabling the onboard graphics does appear to have helped.

Comment: You do understand that the NVIDIA GeForce 8400 GS is over 4 years old right? The card's main feature low power consumption. The reason firefox is slow is because your using your graphic card to accelerate Firefox yet its slower a hug bottleneck.  Seems strange to use a SB i7 with a cheap $50 graphic card ( that what I paid for mine in 2009 ).

Comment: Yeh I know, just didn't bother with a new card as I figured I'n not doing anything graphics hungry. My question is prompted by my surprise that something as simple as scrolling windows or typing text is slowed down by a singular device, which, is in itself, more than capable of handling that basic task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 8400 GS is going to get you a score somewhere in the 3-4 range (Google it and you will see people reporting various ranges depending on the spec).  You can get a much better card for a very small amount of money, or even use the onboard graphics with a DVI/HDMI dongle - actually, most graphics cards come with them for free, I have several at home, so hit up some geeky friends and you can probably source them at no cost.

Given the specs of the rest of your machine, that 8400 GS is definitely going to hold you back, big time.  It would definitely be worth your while spending a little money and getting something a little more modern to power your display, especially if you ever want to run any kind of game on it.  A sub-$100 card like the Radeon HD6670 will net you a 7.1 WEI score and if you hunt for a bargain you may even get something better.

Go to Tom's Hardware Top Graphics Cards for the Money ([May 2012 link](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/gaming-graphics-card-review,3107.html)), pick your price point and then follow their advice - they have never steered me wrong.

Answer (score 1):

While I doubt it's actually slowing your system down, the first thing I would check is that you're running the latest drivers for your graphics card.

Also, check that your CPU isn't overheating and thus under clocking it's self. One time I forgot to plug the CPU fan in on a computer I built and this would happen shortly after boot up.

Finally, if nothing else, the Gigabyte Z68AP-D3 has onboard video (I believe it's HDMI only IIRC, but a HDMI -> DVI adaptor should work) so you could try that without the graphics card in. If anything it could be a BIOS issue, but that's just a shot in the dark.

Comment: Definitely got the latest drivers going. The CPU fan is also definitely working properly. I was quite careful about cooling when building this machine, it's in a pretty large rack case with a huge CPU fan, plenty of ventilation and two pretty decent case fans.

Comment: I love how modern processors have all these failsafe things built in so they die very hard.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I had an issue with the video drivers on one of the machines I maintain, lots of hardware interrupts were happening in the background.  When checking the task manager, the total CPU usage would appear to be about 45-50%, but when sorted by CPU usage, there were no active programs using CPU resources. The processor usage for these items can be seen in process explorer.

This caused everything to act sluggish.  In my case the solution was to allow windows update to get the proper Nvidia driver and install it (for whatever reason the most recent version I was trying to use was not fixing, or was causing the issue). I simply removed them via add/rem programs, rebooted, then did a windows update after enabling 3rd party updates.

It seems the onboard video is pulling some memory, but there could be some sort of issue with it being active at the same time as an addin.  I'd give a shot to disabling the onboard video in BIOS, then go down the driver list for the other devices.

Answer (score 0):

I concur that bad graphics drivers can slow the entire system down.

I tried uninstalling and re-installing the drivers from ATI several times, and it seemed to just make things worse.  Tried manually uninstalling everything in registry and not much helped.

Finally, I ran DDU (http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/display-driver-uninstaller/) from safe mode (f8), rebooted and then let Windows 7 reinstall the drivers.  The machine is speeding right along now.  Sometimes I think little bits might get corrupted, and skipped over in a re-install situation.

Comment: The link is bad.